# "has velocity of" or "has velocity"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What is correct: "The car has a velocity of 50 km/h" or "The car has velocity 50 km/h"?

I tend to say that the first phrase is the correct one. However, it sounds to me a bit artificial. It is a very long sentence for just saying that a physical quantity has a certain value. Are there general guidelines for omitting prepositions?

Comment: In written formal / academic / scientific contexts the "cut-down" syntax of your second version is common. But in normal conversational contexts (where we usually use ***speed*** rather than ***velocity***) we say *My car has a maximum speed of 120mph*, not *My car has maximum velocity 120mph*. In short, it's your *second* version that's "artificial", not the first one. The short version is closer to mathematical notation / algebra than to English as a natural language.

Comment: I would not know what was meant, exactly, by "The car has a velocity..."  The car is moving now at a particular speed on the roadway?  The car cannot go faster than that velocity? Even  "The car has a speed..." is not any clearer.  What is the **real-life situation** you want to describe?  Are you composing a test question? Are you calling the police to complain about someone speeding in a 30km/h area?  Some situations would call for **is traveling at** or **is moving at**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is grammatically correct but, as you say, it does sound quite formal. If you wanted to express the same thing less formally, you could say

> The car's velocity is 50km/h.

Your second suggestion is understandable, but it sounds a bit like a newspaper headline, in that inessential words are omitted.